# ARKit combining ARImageAnchor position with offset values

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do. Let's say I have a `SCNNode` in my scene. (Eg: `ARImageAnchor`) Can be flat on a table or upright.

I'm trying to get the position and rotation if the image and draw a line with an offset value from the `ARImage` when I trigger a button. So instead of drawing line from the centre of the `ARImage`, It should be slightly off-centre depending on the offset values provided. But for some reason the world origin is not set accurately the first time I press the button. If i keep pressing the button it gets accurate progressively and finally gets drawn on the correct coordinates. Sometimes only takes two taps. Below is from the button tap function. `ARSCNView` is initiated when the `ViewController` is launched.

```
var offsetX: Float = 0.05
var offsetY: Float = 0.05
var offsetZ: Float = 0

let arMarkerPosition = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
let translationVector = SCNVector3(x: offsetX, y: offsetY, z: offsetZ)

// Create a translation matrix
let translationMatrix = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(translationVector.x, translationVector.y, translationVector.z)

// Apply translation to the arMarkerPosition
let translationTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(translationMatrix, arMarkerPosition.x, arMarkerPosition.y, arMarkerPosition.z)


let pan: Float = 0
let rotationVector = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0)

// Create a rotation matrix
let rotationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Rotate(SCNMatrix4Identity, pan, rotationVector.x, rotationVector.y, rotationVector.z)

// Combine translation and rotation into a single transformation matrix
let combinedTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(translationTransform, rotationMatrix)

// Create a new SCNNode
let newNode = SCNNode()

// Apply the combined transformation to the new node's transform
newNode.transform = combinedTransform

// Add the new node to the scene
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(newNode)

// Update the world origin to match the new node's position and orientation
self.sceneView.session.setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: newNode.simdWorldTransform)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!